# Why are chains topologically analoguous to distributions?

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-algebras, homotopy-theory, distribution-theory

This question is related to my other question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333903/what-is-the-connection-between-widehat-mathbb-q-g-and-distributions-near-th) but is different enough that I thought I might ask separately.

At the nLab page on [rational homotopy theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/rational+homotopy+theory) it is stated that chains are topologically analoguous to distributions.

Could someone explain this analogy to me? In particular I would like to understand why this implies that the enveloping algebra of a Lie algebra could be thought of as the algebra of distributions supported at the identity.

Perhaps a reference to a good place to read about these kinds of subjects?

Comment: Chains and distributions both push forward; they are dual to cochains and functions, which pull back.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I see, that helps, thanks. Is that "all there is" do you think?

Comment: Well, there's more. Cochains have a multiplication on them analogous to multiplication of functions, and dually chains have a comultiplication on them analogous to comultiplication of distributions (not something you hear much about but it does exist).